# New-CosmosDbContext Context does not contain any resource tokens

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb

When I run:

```
$primarySourceKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$(secret)" -AsPlainText -Force -Verbose
$sourceCosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account 'cosmosAccount' -Database 'bdname' -Key $primarySourceKey -Environment 'AzureCloud' -Verbose
$collections = Get-CosmosDbCollection -Context $sourceCosmosDbContext -Verbose
```

I get:

```
VERBOSE: Context does not contain any resource tokens.
```

and pretty much blank, this was working and returned a list of dbContainers a short while ago but for some reason it no longer works, I did double check each parameter passed in as well as made sure that I use a valid token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

I used the same code as yours and got the below error:

[image]

I removed the environment in the code and I am able to fetch the collections:

```
$primarySourceKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$(secret)" -AsPlainText -Force -Verbose
$sourceCosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account 'cosmosAccount' -Database 'bdname' -Key $primarySourceKey -Verbose
$collections = Get-CosmosDbCollection -Context $sourceCosmosDbContext -Verbose
```

[image]